# Possible Sum Of Numbers in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
List1=[1,2,3]
```

I want an output like below

```
[6,5,4,3]
```

That is the maximum sum is 6. 
But what I like to do is I want all possible sums inside that list. 
That is 3+2 , 2+1 , 1+3 , etc.. like all possible ways.

Comment: Can you clarify more? For example, how many numbers' sum are you taking? You are showing here two numbers at a time.\

Comment: That's a problem .. it's depends on the input provided , N numbers are provided.

Comment: @FlashSavitar It's not clear what you're asking for. Do you need this to return the sum of N numbers for every combination in any given list? Because there is no combination of sums in your list which can return `1`.

Comment: Also u need unique sums right?

Comment: Yes , I need Unique sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this work for you?

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

list1 = [1, 2, 3]    
n = len(list1)
c = (combinations(list1, r) for r in range(2, n+1))
c = set(sum(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(c))

print(c)
# {3, 4, 5, 6}
```

The result will be unique sums of each combination of length *r*, with *r* running from 2 up thru the length of your input list.  The result uses a set constructor to guarantee unique values.

In a function:

```
def unique_sum(obj):
    return set(sum(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(
        combinations(obj, r) for r in range(2, len(obj)+1)))

unique_sum([5, 5, 5])
# {10, 15}
```